# Why does $\omega$ exist with $aN(\omega) \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\, 23N)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$ and $N$ a rational positive integer. Then there exists an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is coprime to $N$, not  principle and satisfies the property $$a=N(\mathfrak{a})\equiv 1 (\text{mod}\,23). $$ Why does then an integer $\omega \in K$  exist such that $$ aN(\omega)\equiv 1(\text{mod}\,23N)?$$

N(x) denotes the norm of $x$.

I do not really have an idea but if $$a=N(\mathfrak{a})\equiv 1 (\text{mod}\,23)$$ then $$aN=N(\mathfrak{a})N\equiv N (\text{mod}\,23N).$$
For $\omega \in K$ it holds $$aNN(\omega)=N(\mathfrak{a\omega})N\equiv NN(\omega) (\text{mod}\,23N)$$ but this does not bring me further.

Comment: The claim is clearly false if $ N $ divides $ a $.